# Should I use a submit button, a regular button, or a link to perform this action?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I've created a feed of comments which are retrieved from a MySQL database using a while statement in PHP. The code for this looks similar to the following:

```
<?

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","database");

if (!$con)
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}


$query = "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 0 , 1000";

$comments = mysqli_query($con, $query);

echo "<h1>Recent Posts</h1><br><br><hr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($comments, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
  $comment = $row['comment'];
  $timestamp = $row['timestamp'];

  echo " <div class='card'>
      <h3>Handle: $handle</h3><br />
      <p>$comment</p><br /><br />
      <img src='$file' style='width:60%; margin-left:20%; margin-right:20%; margin-top:5px; border-style:solid;'><br>
      <p style='color: grey'>$timestamp</p><hr>
    </div>
  ";
  }

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

I now wish to make it possible for users to upvote these posts. To do this, the following process would be used:

[image: process]

To do this, I suppose you would need to add something like one of the following to the `echo` part of the feed code:

- `<button onclick = "likefunction()">Upvote Comment</button>`
- `<form name="$postid" method="post"><input type="submit" value="Upvote Comment"></form>`
- `<a onclick = "likefunction()">Upvote Comment</a>`

and then create the necessary function.

Which of these input types would be the correct one for this purpose?

Apologies if this is a rather basic question - I'm still learning the basics of all this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways you can make this possible in professional and more organisable way , i always have used `data` attributes to perform javascript actions for these kind of functionalities , for example:

```
<button type="button" class="js_vote" data-type="upvote" data-post="32323">Upvote</button>
```

- data-type can be used for upvote/downvote just to identify type of vote
- data-post can be used for placing the post id and use it inside the javascript function to identify the post

and then inside javascript function it should look something like:

```
$('.js_vote').on('click',function(e){
var type = $(this).data('type');
var post_id = $(this).data('post');
// and from here perform the ajax request to send the data to the server.
});
```

or if you want to use `onclick` then you can do something like below:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="js_vote('upvote',90239);">Upvote</a>
```

javascript

```
function js_vote(type,post_id){
    // and from here perform the ajax request to send the data to the server.
}
```

Everyone has it's own different way of thinking and logics about implementing the layout / structure of it's own system , i have recommended you the simple and easy way in which you can better organise your data.

At last its your choice on how you want to design it .. Same attributes data attributes you can use them with anchor tags  or even with div or span or any tag you want.

Comment: Thanks for such a great answer. One last question: to implement the first solution you mentioned, would I include the js within `<script>` tags? If so, should it run when the Upvote button is clicked? As a test, I did this, but added `document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "test";` to the js and then `<p id='test'></p>` to the body of the file.

Comment: As a test, I did this, but added `document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "test";` to the js and then `<p id='test'></p>` to the body of the file. When I ran this, I got no result from clicking the Upvote button.

Comment: You can include that code into script tag as well as in some js file it will work on both of them ... Just remember to initalize it on document ready ad far as i know the code that i have given you should work normally as i have used these kind of codes many time ..please double check what you are doing with the code and check the console for error logs if there is any error please post it here.

Comment: And also are you sending the request to the server with ajax ? And <p id='test'></p> should be <p id='result'></p> as uou are refrring to result inside javascript function.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends on whether you want to rely on javascript or the form submit for the action.

If you don't want to use Javascript to submit the form then I'd use the form method.

An alternative method would be using the button element in the form (as a button will submit the form by default) and the 'action' attribute:

```
<form name="$postid" action="./upvote-comment.php" method="post">
  <button>Upvote Comment</button>
</form>
```

If you want/need to use javascript then it depends on whether you want to use the default button styles defined by browsers or the link style. Other than how it *looks*, I can't see any reason that using a link vs a button would behave any differently.

In summary:

- Form is a non-javascript solution which is perfectly reasonable
- button/link 'onclick' are equivalent to one another

It's probably easier to do it in javascript (as you can just manipulate the dom without reloading the page to change the counter).

Answer (score 0):

Use button or `<a>` depending on which is easier to style ( their functionality will be the same). Use ajax inside that javascript function to do the logic.

Answer (score 0):

Any of these elements would work, as long as you have some way of passing a meaningful identifier to your `likefunction()` which indicates the post that is being upvoted.

Both button and input[submit] are useful if you want to submit user data from form fields along with the event click.  But in this case, I'm guessing this is unnecessary, since all the info you need can be injected into the dom attributes of the element being acted upon.

So it's really a matter of which element will be simplest for you to theme and integrate into your dom structure.  Personally I would choose `<a>` as it requires the least syntax, but that's just me.